# Git - Why am I getting the error "subl -n -w: subl: command not found"?

Tags: git

Everytime when I am merging dev branch with my local branch I get the following error:

```
subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge
```

I am getting this error even when Sublime Text is closed however I am not sure if it's complaining about Sublime. Does anyone know how to avoid or fix this error?

Comment: Do you have sublime defined as the editor in a config file? Does it use a full path to the `subl` binary?

Comment: Ran into this problem on windows and solved it by specifying the full path to `subl` (which is **not** the same as sublime; it's a different executable).

Comment: @torazaburo and how dod you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your git editor has not configured properly.You have to give full path while configuring your git editor.

For **Sublime text 3** use following command-

```
git config --global core.editor " 'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl' -n -w"
```

If you have **Sublime text 2** use following command-

```
git config --global core.editor " 'C:/program files/sublime text2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I thought I would pitch in for future readers.  The above answers are valid, but dont explain what is going on.

When you run the `git commit` or `git merge` commands, `git` tries to find the text editor that is configured in the `.bash_profile` on a mac (or its windows equivalent), and tries to open the editor so that the user can enter a message associated with the commit. When it tries to open the text editor and cant find it, it throws the error.  There are two ways to resolve this error:

- Check the path to the "alias" or the core editor and amend as per the instructions above.
- Alternatively, you will be able to accomplish your commit by using the `-m` option.  Eg. `git commit -m "YOUR_COMMIT_MESSAGE_HERE"`, thereby bypassing the need to open the text editor to enter the commit message.

Answer (score -1):

To find if its tool specific issue...  Run following command to see the merge tool configured (command shows all the configuration settings, check in out put something like merge.tool=xyz...)

`git config --list`

Seems the tool is not accessible to git. You can try setting different tool or fix the path etc. Use the following command to set new tool

`git config --global merge.tool <newtoolvalue>`

(system wide and user specific settings are stored in file /etc/gitconfig and /usr/home/.gitconfig resepctively. i.e when you use the option either  --global or --system.) You can use `git config --global --unset <optionname>` to unset the value.

Comment: This doesn't address the thrust of the question which is configuring `subl` to work properly.