# Git Commit on Mac using Sublime 2: subl command works by itself but not during a git commit

Tags: git, version-control, sublimetext2, git-commit

I am learning the basics of Git and have run into an issue while trying to use Sublime 2 as my default text editor for commit messages.

I am using a Mac and the Sublime text editor(Version 2.0.2, Build 2221)

As per instructions on  [help.github](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/) I used the following line:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

However, when I attempt a `git commit` command I get the following message:

```
subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I know that `subl` and `subl -n -w` work as I have tried them in isolation and they launch the editor. So the issue must be when the editor is opened from the `git commit` command.

I have looked at the questions and answers from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186227/git-why-am-i-getting-the-error-subl-n-w-subl-command-not-found), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git/9408117#9408117) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241099/git-commit-error-with-sublime-text-2) and attempted the solutions but haven't been able to resolve my issue.

Comment: On your Mac, where is the `subl` binary?  That is, what does `which subl` say?  Next, check what your `$PATH` is set to when git runs a sub-command (e.g., set `core.editor` to `env` temporarily and run `git config -e` or something, so you can inspect the `PATH` setting).  Probably you need to fiddle with your `.profile` or `.cshrc` as they are probably taking the directory with `subl` out of your path.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry if this isn't exactly what you asked for but I am new to the command line. i) `which subl` command did not return anything. ii) `git config e` returned the following error: `env: /Users/My_Name/File_Name/.git/config: Permission denied
error: There was a problem with the editor 'env'.`

Comment: Someone posted a solution on another forum. The command was `git config --global core.editor "'/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w"`. Does this indicate that the error is the symlink? If so, could someone please post the correct way to establish the symlink so that the command `git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"` can work

Comment: That the full path works still implies that your `$PATH` is wrong, because in general you want things you intend to run (like `.../bin/subl`) directly on your `$PATH`.  I'm not sure what symlink you mean, there is none in your posting nor in the linked help.github.com.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes Git and Sublime Text 2 are properly installed.  See this page if you haven't already updated to the latest version of Git for Mac: https://git-scm.com/download/mac

1. Open Terminal.
2. Run the command `cd /usr/local/bin` and verify `/usr/local/bin` exists.  Create `/usr/local/bin` if necessary.
3. Run the command `echo $PATH` and verify `bin:/usr/local/bin` is present in the path.  Add `bin:/usr/local/bin` to the path if necessary.
4. Run the command `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl`
5. If you get a Permission Denied error after performing step 4, run the command `sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl` and enter your password when prompted.
6. Run the command `subl` and verify Sublime Text 2 opens.  Close Sublime Text 2.
7. Run the command `git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`.  Sublime Text 2 should now be configured as your editor for Git commit messages.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error trying to configure Sublime Text 3 for git commit messages on Mac. Like you, the `subl` terminal command launched Sublime Text 3 but produced an error when used with `git commit`.

I initially tried `git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"` and got:

```
subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Then I tried the following, substituting `subl` with the absolute path:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w"
```

and received the following error:

```
'/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w: /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor ''/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

This was because the absolute file path contained an escaping backslash that is unnecessary. Once I removed the backslash it worked!
The correct `git config` command is:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w"
```

Ta daa!